# Creating View manually

Tags: android

How can I create convertView manually in following method. I read that convertView can be created manually or inflated from xml file.

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)

I am using xml file for layout.

Answer (score 1):

Use [View.inflate(context, resource, root);](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#inflate%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29)

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    final View contentView = convertView != null ? convertView : View.inflate(context, resource, null);
}
```

where `resource` is your xml layout resource id like `R.layout.list_item`.
Something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code inside the override getView method while extending the ArrayAdapter Class

```
if(convertView == null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }
```

R.layout.list_item is the resource to create the view based on.

the parameter "false"  is false to weather to attach to the root.